# Given a Model.title, how to best query for all records with the first letter = X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a table w 200 records. Each record has a title field which is populated. I would like to dynamically pull all records that start with a certain letter. What's the best way to do this with rails/postgres?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LIKE` clause:

```
Model.where('LOWER(title) LIKE ?', 'x%')
```

Comment: Thanks but this seems to be case sensitive, is there a way to make it case insensitive?

Comment: @AnApprentice I edited the answer, you can search within `LOWER`-cased  titles :)

Comment: @AnApprentice note: I've edited the answer and changed `'X%'` to `'x%'`, otherwise your search would always return empty collection.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't too hard, you can just write a custom sql query mixed with some active record goodness. Ex:

`Model.where("title LIKE 'X%'")`

This would return the collection you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a string where for something like that:

```
Model.where("title like ?","#{params[:letter]}%")
```

but i personally prefer to use AREL:

```
Model.where(Model.arel_table['title'].matches("#{params[:letter]}%"))
```